# How to clear a named range without using any VBA/Macros

Tags: excel

I'm trying to figure out a way to insert a button or similar that when pressed, will clear all members of a named range.

Basically, how to replicate this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Range("Input_Cells").ClearContents

End Sub
```

What I want is to have a button, or some similar type of clickable/toggleable action, that when depressed would clear the contents of the Named Range.  I could probably manage this with a listbox with something similar to below, but I'd rather have a prominent button.

```
=if(list_option = "clear", input_cells = "", )
```

Comment: I don't think you can, sorry. VBA/Macros are the answer to this problem, and if you reject them out of hand you won't get very far.

Comment: I didn't say anything about rejecting them, on the contrary I showed very clearly how to do this with VBA.  I'm just curious to see if anyone has found a way to do this without VBA.

Comment: The title of this question unambigously rejects VBA/Macros.

Comment: As formulas cannot affect other cells, VBA/Macros are the only way, so the answer to this would be NO. @MarkRansom should get the credit for his answer

Comment: @DavidZemens Fair enough.

Comment: You could use VSTO which technically isn't macro's, but somehow I don't think this is what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Buttons don't do anything without code to control them.  Even if you use a wizard to make the button, there's still code.

If you're trying to clear a form, then you're out of luck. However, if you just want to hide data from a results tab:

1. Give the user instructions to enter "1" in cell A1 if they want to clear your result cells.
2. Then in your result cells, use `=if(A1<>"1","Some Result","")`

This would have the effect of 'hiding' results at the user's discretion.